# How do I say "It looks like"?

Tags: english-to-german

How do I say ' It looks like'  in German? I'd like to say it in this context : I looks like I am going to Germany again.

Mein Versuch : Es scheint mir, dass ich wieder nach Deutschland fliege.

Comment: To me it feels like it it should be "Ich vermute, dass ich wieder nach D fliegen muß/werde/darf/..."

Comment: @Em1, dann würde zumindest ich „Es sieht so aus, als ob ich wieder nach Deutschland fliege“ sagen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a translation with ”voraussichtlich“ (probably/likely):

> Ich werde **voraussichtlich** wieder nach Deutschland fliegen/fahren/kommen/gehen.

It means that you’re most likely going to visit Germany. In other words, the chance/probability is very high.

Comment: Good idea. Also possible: "aller Voraussicht nach".

Comment: @Em1 Wer sagt "aller Vorraussicht nach"? Das klingt eher wie Schriftdeutsch.

Comment: @schlingel Ich sage und höre es. Ich denke, dass es sowohl gesprochen als auch geschrieben weitaus seltener verwendet wird, aber die Relation gleichermaßen ist.

Answer (score 7):

»It *looks like* I am going to Germany again.«

Simple and correct everyday translation:

»Ich fliege (fahre, komme, gehe) *wohl* wieder nach Deutschland.«

The little word »wohl« expresses probability or assumption.

Longer translation:

»Es sieht aus, als werde ich wieder nach Deutschland fliegen (fahren, kommen, gehen).«

Same thing:

»[Es] sieht so aus, als werde ich …«

Comment: Can I also say '..., als ob..' ?

Comment: @DerPolyglott33 - Yes, you can say it as follows: Sieht so aus, als ob ich wieder nach Deutschland fahre. (Oder fahren werde.) - Funny thing here is the syntax inversion, verb goes to the end. Guess there's some rule for it, somewhere … ;) Question of Hauptsatz / Nebensatz, glaub ich.

Answer (score 2):

The most idiomatic translation would be *Es scheint so, als*, as in

> Es scheint so, als flöge/ginge/käme/besuchte ich bald wieder (nach) Deutschland

Comment: That only works if the person you are talking to is in Germany... "kommen" is not a good translation here.

Comment: Ja, es ging mir auch um die Formulierung *es scheint so*. Aber gerne korrigiere ich meinen Beispielsatz ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Ich würde noch die kompaktere Form

> Anscheinend werde ich wieder nach Deutschland fliegen.

hinzufügen. Wenn die Reise sicherer aussieht, dann

> Allem Anschein nach werde ich wieder nach Deutschland fliegen.